# More than one deployable git branch

Tags: git, workflows, deployment, branching, gitflow

My dilemma is about the **GIT flow**.

Let's assume that I have an application that can be deployed differently (staging release, QA release, production release).

Since the application has **profiles** to be executed as staging version or as production version (it doesn't depend on which branch the executable is) with the same binary, I think it's really useless to create **three different deployable branches**, but some colleagues think that it is correct because we need to clarify the binary purpose.

What for me is wrong is that once you checked out the **staging** branch, you have to force the deploy as staging (it is still possible to select the production version). This problem isn't possible to avoid, so I think that the three deployable branches aren't useful

This is the state they are thinking about:

- branch master : binary + all profiles
- branch staging : same master sources
- branch qa : same master sources

They just want to keep the ideas ordered (I don't think so)

Are both right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  It sounds like they are fragmenting their code base just so they don't have to configure it before using it.  Is that really what's happening?  Cause, yeah that's crazy.

Comment: I actually am facing some similar problems and working through them myself and interested in the opinions of others. Sadly asking for opinions can start more discussion and debate rather than focus on an answer. Can you reword this into a specific question perhaps?

Comment: @CandiedOrange it is already fragmented, but all the configurations are now into the master branch. They want to duplicate the master branch into two new ones, without changing the code.

Comment: Then what are they changing if not the code?  "Clarify the binary purpose" is a mystery to me if the code is the same.  Hell clarify the binary purpose by changing the filename of the executable produced.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @CandiedOrange exactly nothing. All the times you need to process the binary using shell $ build binary.ext -profile Profile name, but nothing is changing between the different branches. You has to know if you checked out the staging branch, so you need to execute $ build binary.ext -profile staging

Comment: Give them a friendly little set of scripts that build the respective binaries with their respective names so they don't hurt their little brains when they build.  If they succeed in branching the code base because they can't handle the idea it's time to look for a new job.  Cause this one is doomed.

Comment: I do not understand this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deploy the branch you need to where you need to.

Now, obviously you aren't going to deploy a feature branch to production. But deploying the latest build from Master to development shouldn't be a problem.

The development branch in git-flow is about being the mainline - that from which the normal process has you branching off of and merging too. The only exception to this process is that of the hotfix branch where you need to grab the current from production.

Lets look at that hotfix a bit more and consider what the deployment process would be when you have three locations.  You probably would deploy the fresh hot fix to dev, make some commits on that branch, and then deploy that to QA and then to prod.

For a normal release process with git-flow you are likely to be having builds off of the development server on `development` branch.  Once you branch for `release`, you will likely have the head of the branch be going to the development server (so the devs working on the release effort can see what the current state is), and specific tagged branches going to QA.  Once QA oks one of the tagged builds, the release branch at that tag gets merged into `master` and then `master` is tagged and deployed to production.

You will *probably* want to have multiple environments for dev.  The head of `release` is one deployment environment, head of `development` is another deployment environment, and maybe even a head of `feature` being another one or five.

You should be able to build any branch for any deployment environment profile. Deploying the current production to the dev server should be doable.

Git-flow itself is orthogonal to where you deploy things. It is about making sure that the different branches have a limited and defined set of roles that they take. By limiting the roles it makes it easier to reason about what each branch is doing and what its state is at any given time.

The only thing that git-flow tries to say about where specific things are deployed is that the head of `master` is production.  Anything else about what you deploy where in your environment is a site specific issue.  Git-flow works just as well with only one production and devs doing all other deployments to their local servers as it does for having production, staging, qa, dev, and dozens of feature servers.

The steps for doing a deployment to any specific server are *completely* up to the local workflow for that server.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the possibility to build the binary for production checking out the QA branch is not so clear as they want. I know it's right, but the only limitation new branches are going to make is the name, nothing else

Comment: @LucaD that is an issue of the specifics for how you create a build and isn't something that git-flow says anything about.  git-flow is only speaking to the role that a given branch has.

Comment: @LucaD one of the things I've often cited is [Advanced SCM Branching Strategies](http://www.vance.com/steve/perforce/Branching_Strategies.html) by Stephen Vance.  And while it speaks more to a centralized server of perforce or svn, the idea of roles that it presents is what git-flow seems to incorporate. I've found that reading that white paper can help in understanding the philosophy behind each role.  Note that the git-flow mainline is *development*, not the trunk/master.